# Mongod - IndexOnly is false even though query and projection are both covered in the index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

The mongo documentation for covered queries[here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries) talks about the queries and projections and to simply turn off the _id field in the projection if you want a covered query. What if you need the _id field though and still want the efficiency of a covered query (indexOnly = True)?

```
 db.collection.ensureIndex({field1:1,_id:1})
 db.collection.getIndexKeys()

 [{
    "_id" : 1
},
{
    "field1" : 1
},
{
    "field1" : 1,
    "_id" : 1
}]

db.collection.find({field1:{$regex:/^\s/}},{field1:1,_id:1}).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor fieldname",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 3582,
"nscannedObjects" : 3582,
"nscanned" : 130511408,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3582,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 130511408,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 20,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 158705,
"indexBounds" : {
    "cdr3_aa" : [
        [
            "",
            {

            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : localhost}
```

Of course if I turn off _id on the projection, IndexOnly returns true and the query is lightning fast. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - I made it more efficient by getting rid of case insensitivity on a space, adding a ^ to speed up the query, but IndexOnly : False. I don't understand why its not true.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/):

> $regex can only use an index efficiently when the regular expression
>   has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is a
>   case-sensitive match. Additionally, while `/^a`/, `/^a.*/`, and `/^a.*$/` match equivalent
>   strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these expressions use an 
>   index if an appropriate index exists; however, `/^a.*/`, and `/^a.*$/` are slower. `/^a/` can 
>   stop scanning after matching the prefix.

In your case you use regex with `i` which means case-insensitive match. So, you should remove `i` from regex and start to search from the beginning of field.

BTW, I don't undestand your search criteria: Looking for one space char `\s` in the field with case-insensitive?

Comment: I have no idea why that case insensitive match was there. I just mindlessly types it in. Thank you for the response. Checking if this works.

Comment: Based on `nscannedObjects` field I could say it uses index to match the query conditions. And based on `indexOnly:false` I could say it can't use index only to return the result. Well, need to investigate why is it...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why, but it seems as though your query is using the `{ field1: 1 }` index instead of `{ field1: 1, _id: 1 }` index. Can you try running the query with the hint?

```
db.collection.find( { field1: {$regex:/^\s/} }, { field1: 1, _id: 1 } ).hint( { field1: 1, _id: 1 } ).explain()
```

It could be that the query optimizer has selected the { field1: 1 } index initially and has not re-evaluated the various plans. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/ for explanation of the query optimizer and how it selects a plan.